# Prove that if $m^2+n^2=0$ then $m=0$ and $n=0$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

Prove that if $m^2+n^2=0$ then $m=0$ and $n=0$.

Given $m^2+n^2=0$ then $m^2= -n^2$.  Because $m$ and $n$ are real numbers, then $m^2 \geq 0$, $n^2 \geq 0$. Therefore, $m=0$ and $n=0$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct.  Or just notice that the equation of a circle, $m^2 + n^2 = r^2$, here is for a circle of radius $0$.  Done!

Comment: For clarity, you might want to specify that $-n^2\ge0$ and $n^2\ge0$ together imply $n^2=0$, which in turn implies $n=0$.

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That argument doesn't prove anything. To prove it is a sphere you would need to prove this first.

Comment: @logarithm:  "To prove it is a sphere you would need to prove this first."  Huh?

Comment: Yes, huh? Sit on it for a while. What is a sphere? What is a distance? What property of a distance is this exercise proving. What you wrote is not an argument for nothing at all. The OP has a lot more clear of what a proof is than you if you think that 'this is the equation of a circle of radius $0$' is a proof of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$m^2+n^2\geq 2|mn|$$ so $$|mn|\le 0$$